# Failed to resolve cordova android using AndroidStudio 2.1.2

Tags: android, cordova

i have followed steps [STEPS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_first_application.htm) and have improted projectName--->platforms->android folder in android studio but when trying to run getting this error : [issues](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86de58351dcc9bbfeb9700c497c298ea)
I am not getting what the issue is ? While i m using 1.7 version of java?

Comment: are you trying to import the cordova project in android studio ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the latest version of SDK Android to compile. This version requires Java 1.8 to work. So you need to use Java 1.8 if you use the latest version of SDK Android.